# match two files with regular expression

Tags: regex, apache-nifi

i have two filenames i want to match with regexec

filename_ult_2016.txt
filename_ult_OK_2016.txt

i kan match filename_ult_ part by

```
^filename_ult_
```

I i cannot figure out how to make a general match for the rest of the filename

really i want to do a filename_ult_* 
But i am forced to do this in regular expression in my NIFI dataflow ftp processor selecting only those two files

Comment: You want to match the rest of the string? Append `.*` at the end. `^filename_ult_.*`

Comment: you can use ^filename_ult_.* to match both files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

havmaage,

you can use `${filename:matches('^filename_ult_.*')}` to match both files.

And then process it whatever you wants in flow.

Thanks